# How to spawn robot in Gazebo from robot_description topic?

Tags: gazebo, roslaunch, spawn-model, spawn, gz-sim

I am trying to launch a Gazebo simulator and spawn a model in the simulator form the `/robot_description` topic. This already worked sometimes but now I get the following error after calling the launch file:

```
[create-2] [ERROR] [1706829850.265189123] [ros_gz_sim]: Must specify either -file, -param, -stdin or -topic
```

This is how I try to spawn my robot in my launch file:

```
    spawn = Node(
    package='ros_gz_sim',
    executable='create',
    parameters=[{'topic': 'robot_description'}],
    output='screen',
)
```

I am using Ros Humble and Gazebo Fortress on Ubuntu 22.04. What could be the problem? How could I try to debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you pass the topic in your launch file is through the ROS 2 param approach.

But the `create` node expects to simply get it through a classical command-line argument, like you would write:

```
ros2 run ros_gz_sim create -topic /robot_description
```

The equivalent in a launch file would be:

```
    spawn = Node(
    package='ros_gz_sim',
    executable='create',
    arguments=['-topic', '/robot_description'],  # <- this
    output='screen',
```

Comment: Thanks! I got confused by the different ways to pass arguments